# how to rebalance mongodb after adding a shard

Tags: mongodb

How do I rebalance mongodb data after adding a new shard

I do not think it does it automatically?

I could not find anything, it's there support for this?

Also the key for my shards is unique

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add a new shard, MongoDB should automatically start re-balancing data according to your shard key.

However, it will not start re-balancing until there is a certain amount of data. So if you don't have few gigs of data, you probably won't see any re-balancing.

If you have lots of data *and* you add a shard *and* it never starts migrating data, then it's time to go to the google group and start asking questions. As it stands, lots of people are using auto-sharding and it is definitely re-balancing automatically.

I'm not saying you haven't found a bug, just that you'll need a lot more data to back that up.

Comment: You were right, I had to wait a little bit. I got rebalanced thanks,

Comment: If you have 80GB of data, then the system will need to *move* ~40GB of data to balance the shards. At full speed, a server hard drive can move about 0.6GB / minute, so that's at least an hour. But you're also probably using the drive for other stuff, so expect a few hours at least.